# Deserialize fields with NonSerialized attribute

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, binaryformatter

I have a problem with Serialization and Deserialization of an object. I have an object Foo with different properties and some of the properties have the attribute NonSerialized. I have some cases when I want to serialize the fields and to read the serialized object with all the fields. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Have you tried writing your own wrapper around the object, and marking the properties as Serialized there?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880666/net-serialization-how-to-selectively-ignore-data-fields or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648858/conditional-c-sharp-binary-serialization

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the class `Foo` you could use the `ShouldSerialize` attribute to control whether the field should be serialized. For a idea how it works you can look here [Xml serialization - Hide null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818513/xml-serialization-hide-null-values)

Comment: I'm using binary serialization not XML serialization.

Comment: Well, in this case the only thing I could think of is implementing `ISerializable` ... which is no fun =), or as Callum said, wrap it